# Multiple linear regression $b_0 = 0$

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I am trying to calculate the coefficients $b_1,b_2, ...$ of a multiple linear regression, with the condition that $b_0=0$. In Excel this can be done using the [RGP Function](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/rgp-funktion-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d?ui=de-DE&rs=de-DE&ad=DE) and setting the constant to FALSE.

How can this be done with a simple Formular?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: You have to minimize $$S=\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-b_1\cdot x_i)^2$$

Comment: Can you give me an example, how to use the formula with multiple regression. I was expacting a variation of the least square method: $$(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you give me an example, how to use the formula with multiple
>   regression. I was expecting a variation of the least square method: $\beta_1=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$

You have the regression function $y_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb_1x_i$. In this case the matrix $\textbf X$ and the vector $\textbf y$ are $$\textbf X=\left(\begin{array}{}  x_{11} & x_{12} &\ldots &x_{1n} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} &\ldots &x_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots  \\ x_{m1} & x_{m2} &\ldots &x_{mn}  \end{array}\right) \textrm{ and } \textbf y=\left(\begin{array}{}  y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{array}\right)$$

In the case where the constant $b_0\neq 0$ the matrix $\textbf X$ is

$$\textbf X=\left(\begin{array}{}\color{blue} 1& x_{11} & x_{12} &\ldots &x_{1n} \\ \color{blue} 1& x_{21} & x_{22} &\ldots &x_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots&\vdots \\ \color{blue} 1& x_{m1} & x_{m2} &\ldots & x_{mn}  \end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I think you are refering to a basic linear regression and not a multiple linear regression. In my case I am using this matrix: $$X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & \cdots & x_{1,n} \\
x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & \cdots & x_{2,n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
x_{m,1} & x_{m,2} & \cdots & x_{m,n} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This is not a multiple linear regression since you have one parameter ($b_1$) only.

Comment: As I have already written, both ways lead to the same result. You can try a numerical example with the follwing data $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline x_i&1&2&3 \\ \hline y_i&2&4&5  \end{array}$$ What do you get?

Comment: Yes you are right, but I want to retrieve more than one $b$ parameter. Basically I need the Formular for the [RGP Function](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/RGP-Funktion-84D7D0D9-6E50-4101-977A-FA7ABF772B6D) (Example 3), with the addition that $b_0=0$

Comment: @J-T I´ve posted both cases. I haven´t noticed that you meant the multivariate case.

Comment: Thank you, this might rescue me ;) I will try it.

Comment: @J-T Good luck. The column with the $1$´s for the constant is often not recognized.